# martingale decomposition problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingale

Let $G_{t}$ be a filtration and $M_{t}$ a $G_{t}$-martingale. Why do we have this decomposition:
$H_{t}=\mathbb{E}[H|G_t]=\int_{0}^{t}h_{s}dM_{s}+R_{t}$ where $R_{t}$ is a martingale orthogonal with M

Thank you.

Comment: Is the expectation without the conditioning on $G_t$?

Comment: God sorry for that . Yes it is $H_{t}=\mathbb{E}[H|G_{t}]$

Comment: You may need some more details, such as what is $h$ etc.

Comment: To be helpful, you may provide a reference where you have this decomposition.

Comment: in fact it's not precised what is $h$  ...it's just written:
Let $H_{t}=\mathbb{E}[H|G_{t}]=\int_{0}^{t}h_{s}dM_{s}+R_{t}$ with R martingale orthogonal to M. I don't know how to upload a pdf file where you could see the context in which it's written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, this is the Kunita Watanabe decomposition. See the post at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413103/kunita-watanabe-decomposition and the presentation http://www.eurandom.nl/events/workshops/2011/ISI_MRM/Presentation/Vanmaele.pdf

Comment: thank you very much for the link you provided. I can now put a name on this decomposition ^^